# Select DATEADD minutes with query SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I add minutes using `dateadd()` with a query result ?

Like this:

```
SELECT dateadd(minute, (SELECT 
                isnull(time1 - time2, 0)
                FROM table 
                WHERE field = 111) , getdate())
```

In this case, the select result is `288` but it don't add

I need ADD this 288 in the function

Like this:

```
SELECT dateadd(minute, 288, getdate())
```

Comment: What is it that you want to do, exactly? Do you want to add the result to the original time1 or time2 or to a new value? Can you clarify your question?

Comment: Have you tried if SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE field = 111 returns anything? If it doesn't, you'll add 0 to the time. You could also change the replacement value from 0 to 999 while testing and see if that yields a different result.

Comment: @AndersUP Return 288 int

Comment: What are the datatypes in the table?

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, time1, time2), GETDATE())
FROM table
WHERE field = 111
```

This will add difference in minutes between time1 and time2 to current date, if that's what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you want is this query:

```
SELECT DATEADD(minute, (ISNULL(time1 - time2, 0), GETDATE())
  FROM table 
 WHERE field = 111
```

The above adds the difference between `time1` and `time2` (*assuming time1 and time2 are some integer values*) to the current date for each record in table where `field` is 111. Note, however, that this *DOES NOT* update the records!

If you would like to update the records (i.e. modify the table as opposed to query it) then you need to use `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE table
   SET someField = dateadd(minute, (isnull(time1 - time2, 0), getdate())
 WHERE field = 111
```

I hope this makes some sense. It wasn't very clear from your question what you were trying to do.

Comment: It did not work because this returns the current date and not the date with the minutes

Comment: @soamazing, what is the type of time1 and time2?  are they numeric or dates? If it returns the current date, it means the ISNULL function returns 0 which means that either one of time1 or time2 are NULL or they cannot be subtracted like that

Comment: if the type is numeric, then what does this query return: `SELECT time1-time2 FROM table WHERE field = 111` ?  Does it return 288 or 0?

Answer (score 0):

If your datatypes aren't correct, this might work for you:

```
SELECT dateadd(minute, (SELECT  
            CAST(isnull(time1 - time2, 0) AS INT)
            FROM table  
            WHERE field = 111) , getdate())
```

I'd still recommend you take a look at some of the other answers for a better structure - i.e. Miky Dinescus code above would be:

```
SELECT DATEADD(minute, (CAST(ISNULL(time1 - time2, 0), GETDATE()) AS INT)
  FROM table    
 WHERE field = 111
```